# Spark JDBC: NullPointerException when loading table

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-spark, nullpointerexception

I have a very simple code as bellow to connect to a SQL server instance in Spark v. 1.6.1
But it throws nullpoinerexception. I could not understand why. This is SQL Server 2014 running on windows 2012 srv. I tried with different versions of JDBC drivers but no luck.

```
scala> val table = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, "news", prop)
table: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: double, Date: timestamp, Header: string, Abstract: string, KW: string, Content: string, Category: string,
string, Source: string]

scala> table.show
16/04/06 23:22:46 WARN SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops is set; assuming yes
16/04/06 23:22:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:397)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16/04/06 23:22:46 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:397)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

16/04/06 23:22:46 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0
ocalhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:397)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:397)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what driver are you using? I would try to use alternative one if it is available.

Comment: I found out that I forgot to run this step on the server upon installing spark: setup winutils.exe and Set HADOOP_HOME. Issue gone after doing this.

Comment: Great, though you might think of all other people who would find this issue on the stackoverflow - just explain what you did in detail, and post it as an anwer, this could be very helpful to others. If you did this mistake - others might too! ;)